# Why does Invoke-Webrequest return foreign characters correctly and cURL doesn't?

Tags: powershell, curl, invoke-webrequest

Normally I use cURL for pretty much everything but I just noticed that it doesn't really return the HTML content properly when it comes to foreign characters, like cyrillic or german umlauts etc.

For example

```
Select-String -InputObject (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-random-rucyr-ig.php").RawContent -Pattern '<div class="address">\s+<h3>(.*?)</h3>' | %{ $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
```

Will return the name of the person in cyrillic correctly.

However, when using cURL

```
Select-String -InputObject (Invoke-Expression "curl.exe -s -L https://www.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-random-rucyr-ig.php") -Pattern '<div class="address">\s+<h3>(.*?)</h3>' | %{ $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
```

The name will be displayed like `ÐšÐ°Ð¼Ð¸Ð»Ð»Ð° Ð•Ð²Ð´Ð¾ÐºÐ¸Ð¼Ð¾Ð²Ð°`

So why is Invoke-WebRequest doing a good job, while cURL is just returning some gibberish? And is there a way to fix the result from cURL?

Comment: It looks to me like a character encoding issue.

Comment: So what happens when you use Curl without the Powershell wrapper? Does it return the correct text?

Comment: I recall lots of people talking about curl not handling unicode correctly on Windows. I'll try to find the posts.

Comment: Using Ubuntu in Ubuntu 18.04 App (under Windows 10 with Windows Subsystem for Linux) `curl.exe -s -L https://www.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-random-rucyr-ig.php -Pattern '<div class="address">\s+<h3>(.*?)</h3>' | grep '<div class="address">' --after-context=10` retreive the good characters.

Comment: @Trix well... somewhat different but still gibberish `╨£╨╛╨╜╨╕╨║╨░ ╨í╨╛╨╗╨╛╨╝╨╕╨╜╨░`. And like most of you already thought, yes I'm using Windows 10. Also tried the same curl command myself on my VPS (ubuntu 18.04) and it returns the cyrillic correctly. Pretty annoying. I think I'll just stick with `Invoke-WebRequest`.